# Which is least intensive - working out the unique hour in PHP or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to work out a way to track impressions in MySQL without killing my cheap-as-chips server that is already doing quite a bit at peak times.

My idea is to simply record impressions per hour. What I need to know is what the least intensive way to get a unique hour value would be.

Follow the advice I found here: https://rollbar.com/blog/post/2013/03/29/using-unique-indexes-for-fun-and-profit I want to create a table that will track impressions per hour.

The tutorial suggest I do something like:

```sql
INSERT INTO hour_impression (hour, impressions)
VALUES (379015, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE impressions = impressions + 1
```

Now obviously `hour` needs to be a unique value but what would be the best way to generate that unique value?

Would having `PHP` work out the hours since the unix epoch be the most efficient way to do this or is this something that I can get `MySQL` to do for me?

If I do this:

```sql
INSERT INTO hour_impression (hour, impressions)
VALUES (DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(NOW()), '%Y%j%H'), 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE impressions = impressions + 1
```

I am pretty confident that it would work but would this cost me too much in terms of the amount of effort the DB is being asked to make vs working this out in `PHP` and then supplying the data.

Would this be quicker or less intensive?

```php
$SQL = "INSERT INTO hour_impression (hour, impressions)
VALUES (" . date('YzG') . ", 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE impressions = impressions + 1";
```

Is there another way I have not considered?

Am I just blowing my mind trying to figure this out and actually it makes so little difference that I should not worry?

Comment: This looks like premature optimisation to me. The amount of time required to do the key lookup and the update is several orders of magnitude greater than working out which bucket to update.

Comment: You could just store the values and process them later as a low-level background task. Cheap processing when they are arrive - more costly later.

Comment: I thought about that. I considered dumping the imps to files in a folder and then using a cron to come along and aggregate them. It could be stopped if the server was too busy and catch up later.

Comment: Store it as a datetime datatype instead of epoch. Floor the datetime value to the hour, then use a datetime function to group or filter directly on the db.

Comment: Maybe you can use Memcached to store the impression and dump it every 5 or 10 minutes to database. It is slight less accurate but it has a better performance.

Comment: Using your already busy db server to keep track impressions is not a good idea. You can check your hourly impressions using a cron perl script to scan your access log file.

Comment: True but I am checking impressions of adverts on certain pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to be most efficient on the RAM used for keys, using an unsigned integer for the date will be best.
Now having it with the timestamp including hours and seconds won't be a very good idea especially if your traffic grows.

```
strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:00:00'))
```

You will have in 24 unique time values every day for each hour.
If you go for the 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format you might get like 80k unique values each day.

Comment: What would be the difference between storing with datetime type rounded to the hour and storing as an integer?

Comment: In the past I have worked with very big DBs and found that datetime can get very slow. Ints on the other hand in an InnoDB table would be in order, quick to search and not too bad to write. Not to mention relatively easy to rotate to archive tables or partition.

Comment: Integers are way faster to work with and datetime takes 8 bytes when int takes 4. Good for RAM saving.